# Pure CSS Arrow Divs in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-grid

Is there a way to create something like this in CSS, but more flexible (e.g. to be used within a CSS Grid cell)? – original post [here](https://sites.google.com/site/cristianmarcelolealdiaz/home/css-triangle-arrow-divs).

```css
#triangles {
  margin: 3em;
  width: 0; /* set dimensions of DIV to 0 so borders collapse and touch */
  height: 0;
  border-color: red blue green yellow; /* top, right, bottom, and left border */
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px; /* width of each border */
}
```

```html
<div id="triangles"></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean more flexible?

Comment: I mean that the triangles shrink and grow in relation to the rest of the shapes around them in the grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `linear-gradient` to easily create these triangles. You can consider separate classes (like below) or use them in one element as multiple backgrounds.

```css
#triangles {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#triangles div {
  height: 100%;
}

.tr-left {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50%, red 0) 0 100%/50% 50% no-repeat, 
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 50%, red 0) 0 0/50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.tr-right {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 50%, yellow 0) 100% 100%/50% 50% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%, yellow 0) 100% 0/50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.tr-top {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 50%, green 0) 0 0/50% 50% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50%, green 0) 100% 0/50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.tr-bottom {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%, blue 0) 0 100%/50% 50% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 50%, blue 0) 100% 100%/50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangles" class="tr-left"></div>
<div id="triangles" class="tr-left">
  <div class="tr-right"></div>
</div>
<div id="triangles" class="tr-top">
  <div class="tr-right"></div>
</div>

<div id="triangles" class="tr-left">
  <div class="tr-bottom">
    <div class="tr-top">
      <div class="tr-right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use SVG for that.

Quick [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/londongrammar/u5hLgmv2/).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F9F871;
}

.svg-box {
  width: 30vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.top {
  fill: #845EC2;
}

.left {
  fill: #D65DB1;
}

.bottom {
  fill: #FF9671;
}

.right {
  fill: #FFC75F;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="svg-box">
    <svg class="triangle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <polygon class="top" points="0,0 100,0 50,50"/>
      <polygon class="left" points="0,0 50,50 0,100"/>
      <polygon class="bottom" points="0,100 50,50 100,100"/>
      <polygon class="right" points="100,0 100,100 50,50"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```